# Get the latest file from a list of files by name and merge it with another file in a Windows batch file?

Tags: merge, batch-file, windows-console

I have a list of files in a folder. They are named like this: 2011-04-14_00-00-24

Example list:

2011-04-14_00-00-24
2011-04-13_00-01-12
2011-07-08_00-00-28
2010-03-12_00-00-45
...

Now I want to get the latest file according to the filename from that list, in this case its 2011-04-14_00-00-24. The file I get should be merged with another file. How would I get the latest file and do the merge for the 2 files?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the latest file with this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /o-n /b') do (set "Latest=%%x" & goto le)
:le
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean with merging; if that is concatenating two files:

```
copy somefile+"%Latest%" newfile
```

Comment: It would be somewhat faster with `/o-n` instead of `/on` and then jumping out of the loop directly after the assignment.